# Convertir en fecha valida

Tags: sql, datetime

Necesito convertir un varchar a fecha valida en sql server.

```
DECLARE @SDATE AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Viernes, 04 Agosto 2017, 07:11:31.240 p.m.';

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @SDATE)

PRINT(@SDATE)
```

Mensaje

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

Comment: This is an English language site. Your question would be better asked at [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com) instead.

Comment: @KenWhite - I can answer this... should I? :)

Comment: but I understand him, hahaha. Sorry. @gad-arenas si es sql server 2012 usa la funcion FORMAT(VALUE,'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt') en el select. y dame un puntito jajaj. And it doesn't matter the language speak, writed or coded...

Comment: @MattJohnson: Certainly, if you'd like. But you need to explain your answer, and you have to do so in English, and the poster may not understand what you write. Presumably, if they were able to ask the question in English they would have done so.

Comment: Guidelines for non-English content: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8239061

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you meant Microsoft SQL Server, and can use SQL 2012 or higher.

Use the [`PARSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql) function, with the `es-MX` locale:

```
DECLARE @SDATE AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Viernes, 04 Agosto 2017, 07:11:31.240 p.m.'
SELECT PARSE(@SDATE AS datetime USING 'es-MX') AS Result
```

[Working SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/2363)

Comment: ok, not work. Result Msg 9819, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Error converting string value 'Viernes, 04 Agosto 2017, 07:11:31.240 p.m.' into data type datetime using culture 'es-MX'. Yes Microsoft SQL Server in Azure.